# What method is best for creating a online web accessible database?

Tags: database

I have been looking for a way to put a database like an microsoft access relational database shared among many people. You used to be able to create a web app but that's no longer supported.

I've heard powerapps is a solution but it looks like it is to be used only by phones or tablets?

I already have a office 365 account with access to multiple applications. Is there anything that can be used to create what I am asking using those services?

Or do I need to look into SQL databases?

Comment: Could I just store a access file on a onedrive or sharepoint?

Comment: remote desktop setup for hosting the database seems to be the easiest option

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that classic Microsoft Access is not web/browser based (after an attempt was stopped by Microsoft).

A browser based web database requires a back end database that supports the front end web server.  In the Microsoft family that would be SQL Server behind IIS.  This is all mainstream stuff - but an order of magnitude more complicated than classic Access.  There are of course competing brands besides Microsoft - the most well known being the LAMP stack.

There exists a group of web database services, as an alternative: Knack, QuickBase, Zoho, etc.  With these one must live with the User Interface and feature set they offer.

For a windows application (i.e. Access) with geographically separated users one would rely on the terminal services technology by deploying a Remote Desktop Server.  This is primarily oriented towards internal users - not public facing.

Comment: Can't say enough good things about Knack. Really nice feature set, especially for accessing and managing related records, user-based views, and 3rd-party integrations. http://knack.com